# Show favicon of each website in body of html

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to show the  tag in html along with url. Is it possible to show the favicon of each url from internet? (instead of adding  before each , i want to show the favicon automatically)

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://google.com">Google.com</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://example.com">Example.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can add a script tag and loop over each item in the list, append the standard favicon filename (favicon.ico) to that item's url and then create an image element with that url as the source

Example:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://google.com">Google.com</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://example.com">Example.com</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
  for (let element of document.getElementsByClassName("link")) {
    var faviconImage = document.createElement("img");
    faviconImage.src = element.children[0].href + "/favicon.ico";
    faviconImage.classList = "faviconImage";
    element.appendChild(faviconImage)
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google favicon snatcher:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  Stackoverflow.com
  <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prepend favicons to all links, except internal links or non-http links, that are wrapped inside a parent container with `favicon` class.

Also, it may be better to use Google's favicon snatcher in terms of speed rather than manually grabbing it from each domain as shown by Lebster in his answer.

```js
var host = window.location.host;
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.favicon a');
var googleFaviconGrabber = "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=";

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];

  // Skip all internal links and non HTTP links

  if (link.href.match("^https?://") && !link.href.match(host)) {

    var domain = link.href.split("/");

    // Apply some CSS styles to the hyperlinks
    link.style.background = "url(" + googleFaviconGrabber + domain[2] + ") center left no-repeat";

    link.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    link.style.padding = "5px 5px 5px 20px";
    link.style.textDecoration = "underline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="favicon">
  This demo shows how to add favicons to external links using javascript. Check out this link to
  <a href="https://codegena.com">Codegena</a>.

  <ul>
    <li> <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">CSS Tricks</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.in">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://unheap.com">Unheap</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.canva.com/">Canva</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```